# passing section id in mvc using @Url.Action so that user will be scrolled to a particular section after redirecting

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I am a web designer but I am told to design static pages in mvc where rather then using href="some url" I have to use href="@Url.Action("Controller", View)" Now I want to pass a section id in the url so when the user redirects it will be scrolled down to that specific section usually in html this is the syntax I use

```
href="index.html#mysectionid"
```

in Html I have something Like this

```
<section id="mysection">

</section>
```

I want to Know How I am gonna do this thing in mvc. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to concatenate it yourself. Something like `<a href="@Url.Action("...", "...")#mysection" />`

Comment: You can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) of `@Html.ActionLink()` and specify the `fragment`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mix C# code with normal html in Razor:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")#mysection">Test</a>
```