# Linking to a specified section of a page using a TagHelper in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a View called `Legal` controlled by `HomeController`

I can link to this page using the anchor tag or with a TagHelper:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Legal">Cookie policy</a>
```

In the html in the View `Legal` there is a section with `id="cookies"`

With a regular anchor tag, I can have the page automatically scroll there if I do:

```
<a href="/Legal#cookies">Cookie policy</a>
```

When I try doing the same in the TagHelper `asp-action="Legal#cookies"`, the anchor is generated with `href="/Legal%23cookies"`, which does not get picked up by my controller.

I've read [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728068/passing-section-id-in-mvc-using-url-action-so-that-user-will-be-scrolled-to-a-p) how this can be solved using Razor in a regular anchor tag. However, I'd like to do this using a TagHelper. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `asp-fragment` attribute. It defines a URL fragment to append to the URL after `#`.

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Legal" asp-fragment="cookies">Cookie policy</a>
```

It will generate HTML:

```
<a href="/Legal#cookies">Cookie policy</a>
```